# Pandas get_group with value None

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with a column that contains some `None` values. I'd like to be able to do `df.groupby('A').get_group(None)`, but I get a `KeyError` on `None` even though `df['A'].unique()` contains `None`. Can I make this work without converting `None`'s to a string or other value?

Comment: What is your expected output? count the number of nones for each value at 'A'?

Comment: I'd like to perform some operation (like min, or max) on another column within each of these groups. Alternatively I could do `df[df['A'].values == None]['B'].min()`. But I'd like to use `groupby` here if possible.

Comment: could you do a `dropna()` and subtract the two `df` to get only the `None` values

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to perform some operation (*like* `min`, or `max`) on another
> column within each of these groups. Alternatively I could do
> `df[df['A'].values == None]['B'].min()`. But I'd like to use `groupby`
> here if possible.

IIUC, you need to *turn-off* the parameter `dropna` in [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) :

```
out = df.groupby("A", dropna=False)["B"].min()
```

Output :

```
A
bar    4
foo    1
NaN    2
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

*Input used :*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": ["foo", None, "foo", "bar", None],
    "B": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `get_group(None)` and your comment code (which will not work) suggests that what you want is a group formed from the rows with **None** in col `'A'`. In which case no groupby is required, you can simply use:

```
dfx = df[df['A'].isnull()]     #same as a None group
```

and then for example

```
min_b_nones = dfx['B'].min()
```